# Estimate Word files size counting characters

Tags: file

I need to forecast **Word files size** based on the amount of words written. When I create an empty document on Word 2007 ,its size measures 9'943 bytes.When I write characters,about 3000,its seize measures 10'107 bytes. **Why  is the difference only 164 bytes** worth between the written and the empty file,though I wrote about 3000 characters?The value of a character is at least 8 bit.

Comment: This will be a hard task. The file size does not only depend on the characters you write but there's also formatting, paragraphs, page breaks and lots of other sutff unless you really have a document with nothing else but text.

Answer (score 0):

Word uses the [zip file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) for data compression if saving in docx format, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/6846) on superuser and from [www.coolutils.com](http://www.coolutils.com/Formats/DocX):

> The DOCX file is different from the previous Microsoft Word programs,
>   which use the file extension DOC, in the sense that whereas a DOC file
>   uses a text or binary format for storing a document, a DOCX file is
>   based on XML and **uses ZIP compression for a smaller file size**. In
>   other words, a DOCX file is a set of XML files that have been
>   compressed using ZIP.